# How to validate DateTime Laravel

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-5, eloquent, datetime-format

I am saving in the `database` a `DateTime` format for creating an appointment. I have two inputs one for `start_time` and the other for end_time and it saves like this `2019-09-16 08:00:00`. In the view for create I have a `datepicker` for selecting just the date then I have starting_hour and starting_minute and finally I have finish_hour and `finish_minute` and for joining it for the correct format of `DateTime` I did this:

```
$appointment->start_time = "".$request->date_request." ".$request->starting_hour .":".$request->starting_minute.":";
$appointment->finish_time = "".$request->date_request." ".$request->finish_hour .":".$request->finish_minute.":";
```

So it saves like this `start_time: 2019-09-16 08:00:00` and `finish_time: 2019-09-16 08:00:00`. The problem I have is on the validation because it is for appointments so finish_hour can not be before start_hour. The date won´t change because it is for appointments for one hour so i will use the same day but when trying to validate the hour I have problems. I have tried **with**:

```
'starting_hour'    =>  'required',
'starting_minute'   =>  'required',
'finish_hour'   =>  'required|after:starting_hour',
'finish_minute'    =>  'required',
```

But when trying to save I **get**:

```
The finish hour must be a date after starting hour.
```

I am guessing this is because `Laravel` validation thinks also the date must be after the starting date but I only want the hour to be after the `starting_hour`. So how can I validate just the finish_hour to be after the `starting_hour`?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [gt](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) or lt in the validation. For example

```
    $request['finish_hour'] = 5;
    $request['starting_hour'] = 6;
    $request->validate([
        'finish_hour'   =>  'gt:starting_hour',
    ]);
```

it will give you the validation error.
[image: validation error]

And this will pass the validation.

```
$request['finish_hour'] = 5;
    $request['starting_hour'] = 4;
    $request->validate([
        'finish_hour'   =>  'gt:starting_hour',
    ]);
```

Comment: Then accept the answer. And tick the answer to make it valid for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your hours are a number (or string representation of a number), while `after:field` only works with dates.

If your hours are in military time (0-23), you should be able to use the `gt:field` (greater than) rule.

```php
'finish_hour' => 'required|gt:starting_hour',
```

If not and you use (1-12), it will require more complex validation.  For example, an appointment from 12 pm to 1 pm would fail because 1 is less than 12.